# Why does the Ubuntu website recommend a software CD burner program that installs unwanted extras?

Tags: installation, burning

It took an hour to uninstall all the extras installed by the recommended CD burner program - infrarecorder.

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

See the section entitled "Windows 95 / 98 / ME / 2000 / XP / Server 2003 / Vista7"

I still might have to restore my computers hard drive. Infrarecorder installed numerous unwanted programs and changed all kinds of settings in Chrome and how many other places that I haven't found yet??

So why does ubuntu recommend this CD burner that installs unwanted extras?

Comment: This question may be useful in its edited form because it illustrates a possible caution (described [below](http://askubuntu.com/a/347238/25656)) that MS Windows users need to observe re. installing software from SourceForge.

Answer (score 6):

Thats not InfraRecorder but SourceForge, they bundle a lot of stuff along with the installer. It has nothing to do with InfraRecorder.  You can opt out during the install you, just have to read the dialog.

Comment: Just a note, I was able to install InfraRecorder without any adware being mentioned. v0.53. I haven't tested it much, though

Comment: @minerz029 I can't test because luckily I'm in a Windows free zone right now but I know recently through experience that SourceForge have now taken over installers and bundle in bloatware gotta make some money somehow.  It is easy to opt out.

Comment: It is a shame sourceforge has taken this route. The fault is with the person installing though since bundled offers are completely transparent with a clearly defined option to Decline. The user cannot continue on with the installation until they accept or decline

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share a few recommendations of mine to clean your computer of ad-ware (installed by this or otherwise). This may not answer the question but I think it'll be good to have on this page.

---

Possible ways to remove the ad-ware (sorted from most preferred to least)

- Pay attention to the installer, it will have a option to prevent the ad-ware from being installed in the first place
- Use [AdwCleaner](http://general-changelog-team.fr/en/tools/15-adwcleaner) by Xplode. It's a small portable exe file that'll scan and remove ad-ware from your computer. 
  Follow [these instructions](http://general-changelog-team.fr/en/tools/44-english/tutorials/software/313-how-to-use-adwcleaner-version-3-x#telechargement) for how to use it (the following is an excerpt from that link)

  1. Download the program from [here](http://general-changelog-team.fr/en/downloads/viewdownload/20-outils-de-xplode/2-adwcleaner). Click the large download icon.
  2. Run the downloaded file.
  3. Click on the [Scan] button, wait for it to finish.
  4. Uncheck items that you don't want removed from the various tabs.
  5. Click the [Clean] button to clean your computer (all programs will be closed), wait for it to finish.
  6. An information window appears, read it carefully
  7. It may need to restart your computer. If it does, do so
- Use Revo Uninstaller to try and uninstall the offending ad-ware. [Download here](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)